# Providing defaults if params aren't present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a function that will return defaults if date parameters are not set.

If params[:start_time] not `present?` return `DateTime.now` and if params[:end_time] not `present?` return `1.week.from_now`

I'd like to keep these two checks in one function but I can't get it working. If there a better way?

```
  # Main search function
  def self.search params, location
    self
    .join.not_booked
    .close_to(Venue.close_to(location))
    .activity(Activity.get_ids params[:activity])
    .start_date(valid_date params[:start_time])
    .endg_date(valid_date params[:end_time])
    .ordered
  end

  # Check if date is nil
  def self.valid_date date
    if date
      date.to_datetime
    elsif date == params[:start_time]
      DateTime.now
    elsif date == params[:end_time]
      1.week.from_now
    end
  end
```

Asked another way:

What's the best way to combine these two functions?

```
  # Check if date is nil
  def self.check_start date
    date.present? ? date.to_datetime : DateTime.now
  end

  def self.check_end date
    date.present? ? date.to_datetime : 1.week.from_now
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not a hard requirement to combine those two methods, you can simply and easily have these two different methods for checking the validity of `start_time` and `end_time`:

```
  def self.validate_start_date start_date
    start_date.present? ? start_date.to_datetime : DateTime.now
  end

  def self.validate_end_date end_date
    end_date.present? ? end_date.to_datetime : 1.week.from_now
  end
```

Then, in your main search function use them accordingly (`start_date(validate_start_date params[:start_time])` and `end_date(validate_end_date params[:end_time])`):

```
  # Main search function
  def self.search params, location
    self
        .join.not_booked
        .close_to(Venue.close_to(location))
        .activity(Activity.get_ids params[:activity])
        .start_date(validate_start_date params[:start_time])
        .end_date(validate_end_date params[:end_time])
        .ordered
  end
```

Comment: It's not a hard requirement. I might just do it that way and move on.

Comment: This way, it remains simpler and cleaner than messing those if/else in one single method. IMHO.

Comment: Yea I'm just going to go with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding but why not:

```
def self.check param
    result = 1.week.from_now
    if param[:end_time].present?
        result = param[:end_time].to_datetime
    end
    return result
end
```

Your second "end_time" check will always overwrite any possible result from your "start_time" if we put it into one function.

Comment: @Batman This doesn't really solve your problem. It just serves to illustrate that achieving the functionality you want in a single function isn't feasible. Unless you'd like to return multiple objects and assign afterwards.

Comment: I see, that's good to know. I ended up using 2 functions instead. It was simpler. Thanks.